# JSON parse valid rows of invalid string

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I need to parse a json string with JSON.parse() but somethimes the input is not in the full format. for examle:

```
{
    "x" : "x",
    "x1" : "x1",
    "x2" : "x2,
    "x3" :
```

And the parsing is breaking obviously. But in this case I want to "save" the valid rows.

Is it possible?

Comment: You'd have to write your own parser.

Comment: Nope. Unless you want to write your own parser.

Comment: no. json is either syntactically valid, or it's not json. you'd have to extract the individual bits manually, or "fix" the string so it becomes valid json.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the source that provides this data? Why is it not providing "" where there is no value?

Comment: For it to be parsed it must be a valid JSON string, unless you somehow "fix" it before feeding it into the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
String.prototype.safeParser = function(){
    try{
        var that=this;
        return JSON.parse(this);
    }
    catch(err){
        if(this.length<3){
            return {};
        }
        else if(this.charAt(this.length - 1) == "}"){
            that = this.substring(0, this.length - 2) + "}";
        }
        else{
            that = this.substring(0, this.length - 1) + "}";
        }
        return that.safeParser();
    }
}
```

and use it like `console.log(json_string.safeParser());`

It checks whether the string is valid json, if it is not, it looks if it ends with curly braces, it removes one character at a time until it is valid json.

**Note**: this specific code only works for objects with curly braces, not arrays with square brackets. However, this might not be too hard to implement.

## JS Fiddle Demo

 (open your console)